# CSS Media Queries - IE8 still not function

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, responsive-design, media-queries

i got a bit careless by provide a website with twitter bootstrap, and i found out that IE8 still not support media queries...

i google and found two solution:
http://ghita.org/tipoftheday/css-media-queries-for-ie
and
http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

but both of it, can't solve my problem, as i shown here:
http://www.doxadigital.com/scrape/mediaqueries.html (using css3-mediaqueries.js)
and
http://www.doxadigital.com/scrape/mediaqueries2.html (using css-media-queries-for-ie.js)

any idea how to solve my problem, as my site use several @media

Thanks

Comment: Please always include the relevant code within your question.  External links are great but if they cease to exist, your question should still be useful to others.  At the very least, include the css rules which are not working.

Comment: You have the wrong DOCTYPE, try HTML5's doctype and try again: `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: You said "IE8 still not support media queries". FYI, IE8 will never suport media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to switch to the [HTML5 doctype](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_doctype.asp). Second, IE8 does not natively support Media Queries, so you will need to use a JavaScript polyfill such as [Respond](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to allow for responsive elements.

Comment: it seem the format should be "@media screen and.... ", because without adding 'screen and' the script does not work. I usually use this format @media (min-width:xxxx) as shown in bootstrap site.

Answer (score 0):

i`m a web developer, i used bootstrap in a press site but it does not worked on IE8, i used css3-mediaqueries.js javascript but still not working. if you want your media query to work with this javascript file add screen to your media query line in css

here is an example :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>

<style>
     @media screen and (max-width:900px) {}
     @media screen and (min-width:900px) and (max-width:1200px) {}
     @media screen and (min-width:1200px) {}
</style>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
```

css Link line as simple as above line.